Honda CR-V 2005 - top stop light mounting
I'm sorting a few things with my father-in-law's 2005 Honda CR-V. Recently the rear window (on the tailgate) was smashed.  He had it replaced, however now I'm struggling to understand how the centre stop light is to be mounted back onto the glass. The light assembly has two holes, however these seem to be for screwing the light onto some sort of mount, which should be fixed to the glass - and it's missing from the replacement glass.
He tried using construction silicone adhesive, but that doesn't hold very well.  I'd rather get it done properly though.
Any idea how this is supposed to be mounted?  And maybe even the part number for the mount that should attach to the glass?
